# How to Upload png file to database using url?

Tags: database, file, url

hi fellow programmers I am new in web programming, I have a task that I need to upload png files to sql database using url.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect ($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);

mysqli_select_db($connection,$db_name);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO figures (Id, Name, Image) VALUES ('".$_GET['id']."', '".$_GET['Name']."', '".$_GET['Image']."')";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);
```

Those lines used to send data , in this way I can upload VARCHAR to the database how ever I cannot upload png ,I don't know how to define file path here. (Maybe if you know easier solution for my task, could you please share it? ) 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set the sending form to multipart and also change the method to **POST**:

```
<form method="POST" action="uploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myfile">
 <input type="text" name="id">
 <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

in PHP page you can get the file data using $_FILES:

```
// I dont know what is id here? shouldn't be the auto Primary key?
$id=$_POST['id']; 
//Get name of file
$imageName=$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]; 
//Get the binary data of the image 
$imageData= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['temp_name']));

$connection = mysqli_connect ($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysqli_select_db($connection,$db_name);
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO figures (Id, Name, ImageData) VALUES ('$id', '$imageName', '$imageData')";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);
```

Please note that the type of column imageData should be **BLOB**.

As you have mentioned the you are new to programming, I have to say that you have this option too to uplaod the file directly to the server and only save the url in database.

Comment: Thank you Ali , I know how to do it by submit button but what I really want is :
    "http://localhost/Website/imageData.php?Name=first_pic.png&Image=_____ " using url in a way that I can upload pics to database in from my file folder ,I need to write the file path to the place of underscores. :) . Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: There is no way to pass the direct address of local files to the forms inside browsers. The browser only parses the file data and restricts access to the actual path of files.@KananYagublu If you need this to wok just on your own localhost or just on the server files, I have to suggest another way to read files using serverside process. But you can not read visitors file from server.